# Is there a 64 bit version of Pex (Academic license)?

Tags: pex

The Academic license of Pex seems to come only in a 32 bit version.

Is there a 64 bit version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [release note page](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/releasenotes.aspx#0.6.30728.0) version v0.91.50418.0 has been the first with x64 support.

Furthermore, according to [Pex requirements](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/downloads.aspx) you need one of the following OS to install Pex:

> Windows 7 32bit / 64bit, W2K8 32bit /
>   64bit, Windows Server 2008 R2 Other
>   versions of Windows (XP, W2K3, Vista)
>   should work but are untested.  x86,
>   x64 and Wow64 (32-bit running 64-bit
>   OS) are supported. .NET Framework
>   2.0/3.0/3.5 and/or 4.0

Hope it helps